# Parsing JSON string to values

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm not allowed to import new packages at the customer. I'm only allowed in the area between obtaining a `String` object looking like a JSON string and a return, where I'm supposed to return some parts of it in a `List<String>`.

I feel terribly limited and as far I can see, I can't proceed. My best bet is using `Regex` object but perhaps there's a smoother solution? (I believe I'm allowed to use XDocument too, and LINQ, if that's of any help).

Suggestions?

Comment: It looks like JSON or it is actual JSON?

Comment: There are plenty of open source libraries that'll parse it for you.  You can import them as code rather then as a dll.

Comment: What a ridiculous constraint. Looks like you'll need to learn a bit of parsing theory.

Comment: Could you give a example of the string?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's not an object. It's just a string. It's received from a web service that distributes JSON objects. Make you judgement. :)

Comment: @ChaosPandion Yes. But that's the customer's requirement. They'll be looking over my shoulder as I type the code too. Security issues having gone wild, hehe.

Comment: @Frederiek {"something":["something":"something", "something":["something":something"]]}. This type of thingy.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson And what's JSON? It's a string. Clarify if it's standard JSON or a reinvented JSON wannabe :D

Comment: @R0MANARMY I'll see pigs flying over the frozen hell before they'll let me download anything. I'll be only allowed to type in the code. The compile process is done by the supervisor. It's an insanity. But they pay, so I do the work. Hate it but do it.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer No idea. I only saw it once and it was just a peek. I'm supposed to get back there next week and finish the job. :(

Comment: @AndreasJohansson See you next week!! :D

Comment: @AndreasJohansson and you know what json will return?

Comment: @Frederiek Supposedly, there will be a field called *customers* with *customer* containing *custid* and *custnamae*. I'm supposed to get that into a `List<Customer>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [manual](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) and you should be able to do it.

You only need to import System.Runtime.Serialization.dll (standerd .net dll)

edit:

You have this method

```
public static T JsonDeserialize<T> (string jsonString)
```

If you know what json you will get you can create object like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
string jsonString = "{\"Age\":28,\"Name\":\"Tom\"}";
Person p = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<person>(jsonString);
```

edit2:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "[{\"Age\":28,\"Name\":\"Tom\"},{\"Age\":18,\"Name\":\"Andes\"},{\"Age\":32,\"Name\":\"Lily\"}]";
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<Person[]>(json));

    }
```

Edit 3:
JsonHelper is a class implemting a default settup.

```
/// <summary>
/// JSON Serialization and Deserialization Assistant Class
/// </summary>
public class JsonHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// JSON Serialization
    /// </summary>
    public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
        string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        return jsonString;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// JSON Deserialization
    /// </summary>
    public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
        T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: you make the assumption that .net is allowed- i work with customers who do not allow it at all

Comment: @TomBeech well since it is tagged C# I assumed that yes

Comment: Suppose they'll let me do that. Then what? I've checked on my computer and there's a factory that I'll need to use to get a parser but I'm not clear on how to get that to convert the string to anything useful.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson what do you mean with "there's a factory that I'll need to use to get a parser"?

Comment: I was looking into what's in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace. Also, I don't seem to be able to find `JsonHelper` in any namespace. Where do you find it?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Yes, that's the post you so kindly gave a link to. The problem is that I'm pretty certain they won't let me add anything outside the `String json = get();` and `return List<Customer>`. Remember, the challenge lies with the extreme constraint of where to put the code. Also, the object used to serialize the string is not the same as I'm supposed to deserialize into.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson The shortest i can get this is: 

`String json = get();`

`DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customer[]));`

`return new List<Customer>(ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))))`

Comment: I'm not clear on how `Customer`is designed. I'm afraid that there's a need for it to be facilitated with attributes in order to be matched by the serializer. How else will the computer know what goes where? Or am I complicating stuff?

Comment: @AndreasJohansson If the members from the json fit the members off costumer it will work.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll give it a try but judging by the looks, I'll need to declare a class and a sub-class as data contracts. Darn...

Comment: @AndreasJohansson i think other solutions will be code heavy too

Comment: I just guided the customer over the phone (he typed while I talked) and apparently, we've got it **almost** working. Mostly thanks to you. So, I'm checking the reply as an answer, thanking you a lot and asking you to take a look at the follow up question that I've posted here.

Comment: Sorry - it's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778082/how-to-deserialize-a-nested-object).

Comment: @AndreasJohansson glad i could help ^^ i'll check it when i have some time but now i got to work

Comment: @Frederiek I got it to work, finally, once I was allowed to add more classes to their code. At a point I was considering getting a hit man... You've been of great help, F. Thanks!