# How to deserialize a nested object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I've managed to create a deserialization by creating a data contract class (after nagging on the customer a metric ton). My problem is that both the fields I've declared, are returning empty stuff. So, I've looked at it and realized that the JSON object is nested and I'm unclear on how to access the parts that are inside.

The data contract is like this but I'm getting *Bopp* as null (or empty string, not sure which) and *Mopp* as a bunch of zeros.

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
  [DataMember(Name = "Beep")]
  public String Bopp;

  [DataMember(Name = "Meep")]
  public Guid Mopp;
}
```

I **thought** that the data was on this form.

```
[
  {"Beep":"beep1", "Meep":"meep1"},
  {"Beep":"beep2", "Meep":"meep2"},
  {"Beep":"beep3", "Meep":"meep3"}
]
```

However, apparently, they moved the object **inside** an other so it's more like this.

```
[ "root":[
  {
    "A":"some",
    "B":[
      {"Beep":"beep1", "Meep":"meep1"},
      {"Beep":"beep2", "Meep":"meep2"},
      {"Beep":"beep3", "Meep":"meep3"}],
    "C":"some"
  },
  {
    "A":"some",
    "B":[
      {"Beep":"beep1", "Meep":"meep1"},
      {"Beep":"beep2", "Meep":"meep2"},
      {"Beep":"beep3", "Meep":"meep3"}],
    "C":"some"
  }
]]
```

How can I redesign the data contract to make it access the right fields? Or am I missing something and the name of the data member mustn't differ from the field (i.e. *Beep* and *Bopp* won't work)?!

EDIT:

As requested, I'm posting (almost) live data from the string.

```
{"CustomerStatuses":[{
  "Information":[{"Guid":"1","Role":"Customer"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":4},
  "Information":[{"Guid":"5","Role":"Customer"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":6},
  "Information":[{"Guid":"7","Role":"Seller"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":6},
  ...
```

And here's the actual data contract.

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
  [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
  public String Status;

  [DataMember(Name = "CustomerId")]
  public Guid Guid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure needs to match the Json:

```
<DataContract> 
Public Class Customer 

<DataMember(Name:="Status")> 
Public Property Status As Int32 

<DataMember> 
Public Property Information As Object 

<DataMember> 
Public Property CustomerId As String 

End Class 




Public Class Customers 

Public Property CustomerStatuses As List(Of Customer) 

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry - I meant to make it shorter and more generic. Perhaps a mistake. Are you saying that my properties in the class **must** match the names from the JSON string?! Can't I map them somehow (I thought `DataMember` was there for that purpose). Also, are you saying that I **have** to set up the multi-class structure to read the JSON string? I was hoping for connecting into the structure somehow and read just a portion of it.

Comment: I prepared and posted an update showing the actual structure of the JSON string. I hope this help you help me. :)

Comment: You could try the Json.NET library instead of the contract serializers.  It should let you deserialize without a class structure.

Comment: Anything that deserializes to a formal object will require the full class structure.  The contract serializers should respect the `DataMemberAttribute` on the properties.  Json.NET will allow you to deserialize to an object graph without a formal structure.

Comment: I can't. The customer is extremely difficult. I need to resolve it this way. I might be able to talk them into declaring an extra class but that's it. They are not allowing anything else - just talked to them on the phone. I know, it's a huge PIA.

Comment: The customer may not have a choice.  Deserialization has certain requirements.  They don't get to say, "Deserialize this Json, but do it using this can opener instead of a Json Deserializer, oh, and deserialize it into a puppy dog instead of a customer, but don't create a puppy dog.. just kinda pretend theres a puppy dog there.. somewhere."

Comment: :D   I want a puppy now... But seriously, though - I think i can talk them into creating more classes. However, at this point, I'm so stressed out I can't think straight. What do I miss in my class structure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24206/discussion-between-dan-o-and-andreas-johansson)