# How to debug not-working JSON parsing?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

This is a **follow-up** question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778082/how-to-deserialize-a-nested-object/14778175#14778175). I asked how to parse and I got an answer. Having said that, I still don't get it to work but it's probably not due to the answer being insufficient.

I'd like to debug the misbehavior but I frankly don't know how.

This is my deserialization code.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer 
  = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Customer));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToParse));
Envelope customer = (Customer)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

return "Status = " + customer.Status + " and guid = " + customer.Guid
```

This is the data contract I use.

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
  [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
  public int Status;

  [DataMember(Name = "CustomerId")]
  public String Guid;

  [DataMember(Name = "Information")]
  public Object Info;
}
```

This is the head of the text to be parsed.

```
{"CustomerStatuses":[{
  "Information":[{"Guid":"1","Role":"Customer"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":"4"},
  "Information":[{"Guid":"5","Role":"Customer"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":"6"},
  "Information":[{"Guid":"7","Role":"Seller"}],
  "CustomerId":"12345678-1234-1324-1234-123456781234",
  "Status":"6"},
  ...
```

The problem is that the property *Status* comes out as 0 and *Guid* as null or empty string. I'm just not hitting them. What can be wrong here and how do I debug it?

Comment: If you got them to cave on letting you use `DataContractJsonSerializer`, may as well go for broke and ask for JSON.NET.  Even Microsoft [ships it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) with some of their products: *We on the web team will be including JSON.NET as the default JSON Serializer in Web API when it releases, so that'll be nice.*

Comment: You're missing a lot of relevant code here: the serializer you are creating can't handle the JSON text fragment you posted (I'm assuming it's a collection type), you don't provide the "Information" class definition, you're not referencing any KnownTypes for the untyped Info member...

Comment: @JerKimball I just put it into `Object`. Isn't that sufficient? Perhaps I could even **omit** that field, since it's not being used in the code? I'm also thinking about adding an extra class that has `List<Customer>` in it and a data contract. What do you think? How should I approach it?

Comment: Well, it can't *actually* be an `Object`, I mean, it must be an instance of some type with those two properties - what is that classes definition? Re: the wrapper collection - totally, that would bring in all the relelvant "potential problem areas"

Comment: @JerKimball Actually, it can. When you think about it, it **does** fit into the definition of `Object` type. See my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong section, or barking up the wrong tag, so to speak. You shouldn't try to parse *Customer* but *CustomerStatuses*, since that's your root object. You **will** need one more class. Hopefully your customer will accept that.

Here's the code for data contracts. I've included the field *Info*, because it looks like you needed it but as the specification goes, you can as well omit it.

```
[DataContract]  
public class CustomerStatuses
{
  [DataMember(Name = "CustomerStatuses")]
  public IEnumerate<Customer> Customers;
}

[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
  [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
  public int Status;

  [DataMember(Name = "CustomerId")]
  public String Guid;

  [DataMember(Name = "Information")]
  public Object Info;
}
```

Then, you access the stuff by this code.

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer 
  = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomerStatuses));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonText));
CustomerStatuses parser = (CustomerStatuses)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

String guid = parser.DocumentStatuses.FirstOrDefault().Guid;
int status = parser.DocumentStatuses.FirstOrDefault().Status;
```

And this is definitely going on my blog tomorrow!